# How to get the clicked html element and edit?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I want to get the clicked html elements and edit it after some times.

**What I tried?**

I tried the below one, but I can get the exact html element in html text format, but I can not able to change it. How can I change the value.

```
var _targetevent;

$( "body" ).click(function( event ) {
  _targetevent=event;
  console.log( "clicked: " + event.target); //<p>This is the old one</p>
});

function undateit()
{
  _targetevent.target="<b>This is the new div</b>";
}
```

Comment: `_targetevent.target.innerHTML="<b>This is the new div</b>";` OR as you are using jQuery `$(_targetevent.target).html("<b>This is the new div</b>")`, However where/when are you invoking the method `undateit()`?

Comment: Merbin Joe  If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's how  to do it:-https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work . Do it for your other questions too (if not done yet). Thanks!

Comment: @satpal Thank you, How can I change the whole details including that div?

Comment: @MerbinJoe, Yes, `_targetevent.target.outerHTML = '<p id="test">Test</p>'`

Comment: @satpal 
 
'_targetevent.target => <p id="test">Test</p> _targetevent.target.innerHTML="This is the new div"' It will change the Test word only, but I want to replace all (including <p> tag )

Comment: @MerbinJoe, Use `outerHTML` property, Have you even tried it?

Comment: @satpal Thank you so much dear, I don't know about that property.

Comment: @Satpal  thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Call `undateit()` inside `click()`

2.Use `innerHTML` along with `_targetevent.target`

Example:-

```js
var _targetevent;

$( "body" ).click(function( event ) {
  _targetevent=event;
  console.log( "clicked: " + event.target.id); //get id of the clicked element
  undateit(); //call function on click
});

function undateit(){
  //use outerHTML to completly replace div with new-one
  
  _targetevent.target.outerHTML="<b>This is the new div</b>";
  
  /* if you want to change only content inside element then use inner HTML
  
  _targetevent.target.innerHTML="<b>This is the new div</b>"; //use innerHTML
  
  */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="mydiv">Check change</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is good but it changes only inside the div, how can I change whole div need to use prev()?

Comment: No, I used outerHTML as per the *Satpal* comments.